# Why does setting directory path in cache_store =: file_store make no difference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I set

```
config.cache_store = :file_store, "#{Rails.root}/public/cache"
```

but everything is written directly into the /public directory.

what could be wrong?

Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 3.2

Comment: does `/public/cache` dir exist?

Comment: originally not, but I created it and it makes no difference. Mind I get no error and the request _is_ stored, just in the wrong place.

Comment: config.action_controller.page_cache_directory = File.join(Rails.public_path, 'cache') seems to do the trick. This is from an older app of mine, I wonder why this is not mentioned in the (easy to reach) docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help. It's from the Rails 2.3 doc, though:

> By default, the page cache directory is set to Rails.public_path
>   (which is usually set to File.join(self.root, "public") – that is, the
>   public directory under your Rails application’s root). This can be
>   configured by changing the configuration setting
>   config.action_controller.page_cache_directory. Changing the default
>   from /public helps avoid naming conflicts, since you may want to put
>   other static html in /public, but changing this will require web
>   server reconfiguration to let the web server know where to serve the
>   cached files from.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/caching_with_rails.html

From this it may seem like your problem:

> but everything is written directly into the /public directory.

May be because it was just writing to the default cache dir.